# JQuery event when a checkbox state is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my issue, I want to check make an array with JQuery of all the checkbox that are checked. I perform this everytime a checkbox is checked or unchecked. So I used this code to do what I want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        CBChange();
    });
});

function CBChange()
{
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        alert("checked");
    });
}
```

The problem is "I think" that this is perform before the checkbox that have been clicked changes its state. So if for example I have four checkbox all checked and I unchecked one, the alert message will pop four times like if the script is executed before it set the checkbox to unchecked.

I just need a way to achieve it. The result that I want, if we take the same example as above, is that the message pop only 3 times for the remaining checkbox let checked.

Thanks in advance,
Me!

Comment: Which browser are you using? And how does Ajax tie into your question?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is "I think" that this is perform before the checkbox that have been clicked changes its state. So if for example I have four checkbox all checked and I unchecked one, the alert message will pop four times.

What do you mean "I think"? What happened when you tried it? The change event should be triggered *after* the state has been updated, and in practice that's the way it's always worked for me. So in your example if all four were checked and you uncheck one the alert should show three times.

Here is a fiddle with your code that works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/tMtwX/

Or here's another demo showing the same effect without the annoyance of alert messages: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/WnHBx/

Or if you say `alert(this.checked);` inside your change handler you'll see the current state of the particular checkbox that just changed...

Answer (score 0):

To make an array with all checked items

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").change(function(e) {
        var items=$(":checkbox:checked");
        console.log(items);
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ANtaC/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score -2):

you have wrong  selectors try

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("checkbox").change(function() {
        CBChange();
    });
});

function CBChange()
{
    $("checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        alert("checked");
    });
}
```

Comment: not working, I don't think the problem comes from the selectors. The alert message pop as expected but it's like it doesn't take in consideration the change I just made.

Comment: `:checkbox` is a valid selector to select all checkbox elements. http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ `checkbox` however is not valid because there isn't an element with a tagname of `checkbox`. Checkboxes are input elements.

Comment: sorry for double post not really used to this forum and didn't saw the comments were right below the post

Comment: Yes Kevin B agreed, shooting from the hip and totally shot off toes.